# Scanning for BTRFS files systems

Tags: btrfs

After upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to a point release, I get a message "scanning for btrfs file systems" at start-up. I presently do not have any drives with BTRFS, (am considering it potentially for a future use case). The searching slows the boot speed by an additional 25-30 seconds.

1. What would have caused this?
2. How can I make this not effect the boot speeds?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78535/how-to-get-rid-of-the-scanning-for-btrfs-file-systems-at-start-up

Comment: This looks like it would be a good work around, but is there a way to also tell _why_ this would have appeared randomly in the first place? To try to prevent similar things in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed instructions on the link provided by muru./.:

> The btrfs-tools package adds an action to the initramfs to load the btrfs module. If you purge that package `(sudo apt-get purge btrfs-tools)`,

It still kept a slow boot time, but still slightly faster than when it was scanning for btrfs.

Comment: Your findings suggest that there are other things happening just after scanning for Btrfs file systems that are not logged to the console. I recommend that you create a [boot chart](//wiki.ubuntu.com/UNR/BootChart) to analyse the issue further.